# Doesn't generate logs file in django

Tags: django

[image]I don't know what to do but nothing works, what could be the problem?

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters':{
    'simple':{
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        'datefmt': "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S",
    },
},
'filters': {
    'require_debug_true': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
    },
},
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'console_prod': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'level': 'ERROR',  
    },
    'console_debug':{
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',  
    },
    'file': {
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': BASE_DIR / 'logs/forum_api.log',
        'level': 'INFO',
        'formatter': 'simple',
    },
   
},
 "loggers" : {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console_debug", "file"],
        },

    },
```

}

This error is not clear to me

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging\config.py", line
```

572, in configure
raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console_debug'

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `filters` keys:

```
'filters': {
    'require_debug_true': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
    },
},
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
    },
},
```

merge them:

```
'filters': {
    'require_debug_true': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
    },
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
    },
},
```

Comment: It did not help me, the error disappeared, but the file was not created.

Comment: That's another error. The first error was solved.